# Put updater method in state or pass directly to context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-context

When having context like this:

```
<MatchContext.Provider value={this.state.match}>
```

Should I then put

```
match: {
      match: null,
      updateMatch: this.updateMatch
    },
```

In my state
or is this alright?

```
<MatchContext.Provider value={{
          match: this.state.match.match,
          updateMatch: this.updateMatch
        }}>
```

I read somewhere the latter is bad for performance because it has to re-initialize the object every render or something. Can't remember where I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right,

You should use the first method and store the updateMethod inside the component state.

Because if you create an new object every time the memory value of the state will change and the context will be updated every time the component rerender

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider